# Django displays twice the same message

Tags: python, django

[image]Django displays twice the same message, even when the `messages` are not passed in the `views.py`.

```
#login.html
{% extends 'login_system/base.html' %}
{% block body %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        {% if message.tags == 'error' %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
              {{ message }}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

```
# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import RegisterForm, LoginForm
# Create your views here.
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(data=request.POST)
        print(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            messages.success(request, 'Successfully Logged In!')
            print('ok')
            return redirect('home_page')
        else:
            #print(form.errors.get_json_data())
            if form.errors:
                for error in form.errors.get_json_data()['__all__']:
                    messages.error(request, error['message'])
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Something went wrong. Please try again.')
            print('nie ok')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'login_system/login.html', {'form': form})
```

This code renders `error message` twice for me. One is from the `views.py`, Second I do not know. The `base.html` file can look like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
{% block body %}
{% endblock %}
</body>[![enter image description here][1]][1]
</html>
```

And I can delete sending `message` from the `views.py` and the nonstyled version still is rendered. Why is that?

Comment: Because `{{ form }}` will render the error messages as well. There i thus no need to add these as messages.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks, how can I edit the style of messages from `form` or do not render them at all?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom-formatted Django form errors appearing twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53710769/custom-formatted-django-form-errors-appearing-twice)